# StrongLoop Create models from a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, strongloop, loopbackjs

I need to create a model from a stored procedure. The stored procedure is in SQL Server. I tried using the `discover` api to fetch the model, but it seems loopback isn't that advanced. I browsed the StrongLoop docs to find out if something like that can be done, but dint have any luck.

I am trying to create an API that would return me the data from the stored proc. I hope there is such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems locating how to do the exact same thing.
I have been looking at using this instead.
[Transactional SQL with Sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794784/transactional-sql-with-sails-js)

I do wish sprocs were clearly documented as being doable with strongloop, because I love all the other features.

If it does, it would be with the native query feature:
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Executing+native+SQL

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?